azure web app doesn't pick up the environment variable with docker image deployed
I am deploying a docker image to azure app service. I've added an environment variable to container but it seem to be not available for production code. How can I troubleshoot it?
I am expecting all my environment variables to be here ...

They all seem to be making it there except of MAP_KEY I've added for google maps to work ...

Is there additional settings I should update on the app service?
I've tried restarting the app service and removing/re-adding Environment variable again. It works locally and if I hardcode the api key but won't pick it up as process.env when app is deployed.
I have it deployed here --> https://aigentyportal.azurewebsites.net/map
my docker file .. I've added env name on line 14. I don't want to expose the value in repo, how do I connect it to github secrets or azure container secrets?


Can you share your dockerfile?

To pass the Value from Environment variable in Next.js,you can define the the value in Dockerfile using ENV.
This worked for me.
Dockerfile:
FROM  node:lts-alpine

  

ENV  NODE_ENV=production

ENV  MY_ENV=Vivek

WORKDIR  /usr/src/app

COPY  .  .

RUN  npm  install  &&  npm  run  build

EXPOSE  3000

  

CMD  ["npm",  "start"]

test/page.js:
export default function env(){
    const env = process.env.MY_ENV || "Nextjs"
    return(
        <>
        <h1>Hello {env}</h1>
        </>
    )
}

OUTPUT:


I am committing docker file to repo to build using github actions which means this env variable will be exposed? I have them stored as secrets in github and azure and trying to link my docker image to those somehow.
